# How to Merge Fine-tuned Adapter and Pretrained Model in Hugging Face Transformers and Push to Hub?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface, llama, huggingface-hub

I have fine-tuned the Llama-2 model following the [llama-recipes](https://github.com/facebookresearch/llama-recipes) repository's [tutorial](https://github.com/facebookresearch/llama-recipes/blob/main/examples/quickstart.ipynb). Currently, I have the pretrained model and fine-tuned adapter stored in two separate directories as follows:

Pretrained Model Directory:

```
Llama2-Finetuning/models_hf/
└── 7B
    ├── config.json
    ├── generation_config.json
    ├── pytorch_model-00001-of-00002.bin
    ├── pytorch_model-00002-of-00002.bin
    ├── pytorch_model.bin.index.json
    ├── special_tokens_map.json
    ├── tokenizer.json
    ├── tokenizer.model
    └── tokenizer_config.json
```

Fine-tuned Adapter Directory:

```
Llama2-Finetuning/tmp/llama-output/
├── README.md
├── adapter_config.json
├── adapter_model.bin
└── logs
```

I want to achieve two things:

1. **Merge Pretrained Model and Adapter as a Single File**:
   I have observed that when I push the model to the Hugging Face Hub using `model.push_to_hub("myrepo/llama-2-7B-ft-summarization")`, it only pushes the adapter weights. How can I merge the pretrained model and fine-tuned adapter into a single file, similar to how "TheBloke" does, and upload them together to the Hugging Face Hub?
2. **Push and Load Pretrained Model and Adapter Separately**:
   Alternatively, I'd like to know how to push the pretrained model and fine-tuned adapter from their respective directories separately to the Hub, while still being able to load them together in my Python code for inference, just like how I loaded them from directories using the code below:

```
import torch
from transformers import LlamaForCausalLM, LlamaTokenizer

model_id="./models_hf/7B"
adapter_id="./tmp/llama-output"

tokenizer = LlamaTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)
model = LlamaForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_id, load_in_8bit=True, device_map='auto', torch_dtype=torch.float16)
model.load_adapter(adapter_id)
```

I appreciate any guidance on how to achieve these two objectives efficiently. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think for your task #1 you can use the `model.merge_and_unload()` method to merge the adapter model with the base model.